# Qt: extend QFileSystemModel with another model

Tags: qt, model, tree, qfilesystemmodel

I have a Qt model that represents the content of hdf5 files (but it can be any other container type for this matter). Can I "extend" QFileSystemModel by this specialized model in order to browse files and container items in a single tree view? I guess such a combined model should exist for archive file types but I can't find a single example. A link or advice would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: `QFileSystemModel` is already a very complex class with multithreaded logic. It is not designed for extensions. If you already have a model to work with archive, why do you need to use `QFileSystemModel`?

Comment: >why do you need to use QFileSystemModel? Because I want it in the same view: the archive content as children of the parental file node

Comment: So what is a problem to do a same model? It's just a couple of columns/roles